# C#, basic error

Tags: c#

So I am making a super basic (I'm in my second week of learning C# so please excuse my ignorance) program that takes a string input from a user and outputs the string backwards. I have copied the book to a T in regards to a majority of it but I have noticed spelling errors in some of their code so I don't have a lot of faith in what they are showing. My compiler is giving me an error with WriteLine and ReadLine and I don't understand why as the book says it works. This is the error I am getting;

"WriteLine does not exist in the current context" same with "ReadLine"

My code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class funcStrings
    {

        public static string ReverseString(string s)
        {
            char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(arr);
            return new string(arr);
        }
    }

    class runProgram
    {

        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                string name;
                WriteLine("Enter your name to be reversed ");
                name = ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(funcStrings.ReverseString(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any guidance here

Comment: Should be `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadLine`; I have no idea why the book would leave out the `Console.` bit.

Comment: Try using `Console.Readline` and `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Does the book have `using static System.Console` at the top?

Comment: With a mistake like this, I can't blame you for not having much faith in their code...

Comment: @mason - Did you mean `using static System.Console;`?

Comment: What book is this?  Error aside, the coding style they're using is horrendous.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. Nope in none of the examples does it have Console.Writeline or Console.Readline that I can see - it just has snippits of code instead of full sections. Thank you.

Comment: You would be better off with [C# in Depth](https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth-third-edition) by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: @DangerZone Yes, I meant that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `Console.` in front:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name to be reversed ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Note that as of C# 6.0 another solution would be the `using static` statement as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can add such namespace:

```
using static System.Console;
```

This brings all the static members from the `System.Console` class into scope, so that you don't need to prefix them with `Console.` It is a C# 6 feature, and useful when accessing many members in a static class. See [relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Comment: This is more than likely the actual reason the code is not compiling, rather than a print error in the book.

Comment: Thank you, that's probably why then. The book only seems to put snippits of code into the pages instead of a full blown using static System.Console at the start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that it should be `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is:

```
static void Main()
 {
     string name;
     WriteLine("Enter your name to be reversed ");
     name = ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine(funcStrings.ReverseString(name));
 }
```

You need to add a `Console.WriteLine("Enter your name to be reversed"):`